# HDMI force hotplug

Tags: display, video, hdmi, hotplug

is there any way how to enable **HDMI force hotplug** feature in Ubuntu 18/20 like with *config.txt* parameter `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` on RaspberryPi?
For clarification about what I mean by HDMI hotplug:

> HDMI output mode will be used, even if no HDMI monitor is detected.

`xrandr` output with enabled hotplug feature and without connected monitor on RPi:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
```

We are using Lenovo ThinkStation with integrated Intel® UHD GPU.
I tried this GRUB command https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490211 but it doesn't have required effect like `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` on RPi.

Do you have any tip/solution?
Thank you.